# Import/export configuration and translations

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, importing-exporting

I downloaded the .po file for loading the Italian language and installed it on my local version of Drupal.

Then, I launched the config:export command with drush and I committed the created configuration files

When I imported the configuration on the target machine (via jenkins) I did not find all the translations loaded

In particular, compared to about 7,000 exported translations, I find only 600 imported ones

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The translations are not part of the configuration.

You can configure and export the source of translation files. One option is to have the local filesystem as the source. The translation files are stored locally in the `sites/default/files/translations directory`, but can change this directory on the File system configuration page.

What you could also configure and export how frequently you want to check for new interface translations for your currently installed modules and themes. At
`/admin/config/regional/translate/settings`

Check for updates

- Never (manually, this is the default)
- Weekly
- Monthly

You can manually download the translations at:
`/admin/reports/translations/check?destination=/admin/reports/translations`